# Jquery-Image-Gallery-issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery image gallery but I am facing a problem in next and prev and I should follow the structure which i am using in fiddle demo. Initially I need to show two images on click of next the other images/video should visible

Here it is what I have tried.

I should not use any plugins

http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/41/

Answer (score 1):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/40/

I changed `var $tDiv = $('#thumbs div');` to `var $tDiv = $('#thumbs > div');`

You only need to select the direct descendants of `#thumbs`.

Comment: i edited my structure in fiddle can you send a fiddle demo according to it please

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/T657N/43/. 
Now whatever items you add to that gallery should have class `thumb-layout`

Comment: If I want to show 4images initially after that i need to show another 4 images what to change in that

Comment: Can you help me I need to show 4images initially and onclick of next the other 4images should display